# What is the error with this PHP code

Tags: php, html

I am unable to understand why my php code isnt working. Please look at this small code.

```
<?php
if (!isset($_POST['Ingest']) && !isset($_POST['Play']) && !isset($_POST['Remove'])) {
?>
<html>
<head>
<title> Welcome to VASE Content Management System </title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="<? php echo $PHP_SELF;?>">
Ingest <br />
Path to video master file:<input type="text" size="80" maxlength="80" name="FileNameIn">   <br />
Target Object Name:<input type="text" size="80" maxlength="80" name="ObjectNameIn"><br />
Resolution of Master:<input type="text" size="80" maxlength="80" name="ResolutionIn"><br />
Codec of Master:<input type="text" size="80" maxlength="80" name="CodecIn"><br />
<input type="submit" value="Ingest" name="Ingest"><br />
Play <br />
Object Name:<input type="text" size="80" maxlength="80" name="ObjectNamePl"><br />
<input type="submit" value="Play" name="Play"><br />
Remove <br />
Object Name:<input type="text" size="80" maxlength="80" name="ObjectNameRm"><br />
<input type="submit" value="Remove" name="Remove"><br />
</form>
<?php
}
elseif (isset($_POST['Ingest'])) {
echo "hi";
}
elseif (isset($_POST['Play'])) {
echo "play"; 
} 
elseif (isset($_POST['Remove'])) {
echo "remove";
}
?>
```

The plain HTML part, if copied to a separate HTML file, works fine, but the php code isn't working. I tried another php sample code, but that worked fine, so my PHP server is up and running alright. I am using Ubuntu 11.10.

Error:

> 500 Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from fulfilling the request

Comment: What behavior are you expecting, and what are you seeing instead? Are you getting any error messages or warnings?

Comment: Look in the error logs to see the error message.

Comment: 500 errors get logged in Apache's error log. Look there, it'll have far more information.

Comment: Please edit your post to describe what the code should be doing. That way we have an idea of what you are trying to accomplish before we look at the code. Just saying "Look at this. It doesn't work." isn't likely to garner much attention.

Comment: Is `<? php...` (with a space) OK?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I had included an extra space at <? php. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

on line 9 you have the action set to

```
<? php echo $PHP_SELF;?>
```

take the space out from the ? and the php ... see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong syntax:

```
<form method="post" action="<? php echo $PHP_SELF;?>">
```

should be

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF; ?>">
```

Comment: I think it's not necessary to use `$PHP_SELF`. 
This would work too:
`<form method="post" action="">`

Comment: Thanks, works now. Also thanks for the suggestion @ZeroSuf3r

Answer (score 0):

In your code, Line number 9, remove the space between `<?` and `php`

```
<?php
if (!isset($_POST['Ingest']) && !isset($_POST['Play']) && !isset($_POST['Remove'])) {
?>
<html>
<head>
<title> Welcome to VASE Content Management System </title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF;?>">
Ingest <br />
Path to video master file:<input type="text" size="80" maxlength="80" name="FileNameIn">   <br />
Target Object Name:<input type="text" size="80" maxlength="80" name="ObjectNameIn"><br />
Resolution of Master:<input type="text" size="80" maxlength="80" name="ResolutionIn"><br />
Codec of Master:<input type="text" size="80" maxlength="80" name="CodecIn"><br />
<input type="submit" value="Ingest" name="Ingest"><br />
Play <br />
Object Name:<input type="text" size="80" maxlength="80" name="ObjectNamePl"><br />
<input type="submit" value="Play" name="Play"><br />
Remove <br />
Object Name:<input type="text" size="80" maxlength="80" name="ObjectNameRm"><br />
<input type="submit" value="Remove" name="Remove"><br />
</form>
<?php
}
elseif (isset($_POST['Ingest'])) {
echo "hi";
}
elseif (isset($_POST['Play'])) {
echo "play"; 
} 
elseif (isset($_POST['Remove'])) {
echo "remove";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

"Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO in {file} on line 9"

try enabling the error_reporting(E_ALL);